# How to set buffer settings in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, buffer

How should i bring buffer settings in flex swf? How i achieve buffer setting in flex.
 for example:

I use below code to set buffer time with netstream

```
ns.bufferTime=0;
```

But the delay in playback varies after some time.I want only a constant delay throughout the playback.

Because I want to set buffertime and all buffersetting of my own in actionscript and testing it to find the delay in playback the video.I want to set the delay time in playback video using buffertime.

Help me plz....

Answer (score 0):

You should take into consideration connection time. Your application connects to the server. And you cannot control this time by ActionScript in particular by `bufferTime`. You should tune the server.

Answer (score 0):

You're removing the buffer time -- it would be better to set a buffer time to say, 3 seconds or so.  This will help with "hiccups".

```
ns.bufferTime = 3.0;
```

The standard is around 3+ seconds.  I actually prefer a higher buffer time for larger movies.